# Экранирование строки для вставки в запрос

Tags: winforms, curl, c++-cli

Разрабатываю приложение для роботы с сетью используя c++ windows forms curl 
Хочу с текстового поля отправить текст но при добавлении его просто в запрос (комментированная строка в коде) приложение при запросе вылетает.

Вопрос: как преобразовать символы, чтобы добавить в запрос?

```
private: std::string  ToStringUS(String^ T) 
         {
             string url = "";
             marshal_context ^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
             const char* str55554 = context->marshal_as<const char*>(T);
             url += str55554; 
             delete context;
             return url;
         }



    string url = "http://";
    url += ToStringUS(this->textBox1->Text);
    url += "?dat=";
    //url += ToStringUS(this->richTextBox1->Text);
    this->richTextBox1->Text =gcnew String(URLget(url).c_str());




    private: string URLget(string url) 
             {


 //string url = "http://";
 buffer = "";
              //необходимые CURL объекты
CURLcode result;

//проверяем результат инициализации
if (curl)
{



      //задаем все необходимые опции
      //определяем, куда выводить ошибки
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);

      //указываем прокси сервер
      //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxy:8080");
      //задаем опцию отображение заголовка страницы
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      //указываем функцию обратного вызова для записи получаемых данных
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
      //указываем куда записывать принимаемые данные
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);


      //задаем опцию - получить страницу по адресу http://google.com
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,url);
      //запускаем выполнение задачи
      result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
      //проверяем успешность выполнения операции
      if (result == CURLE_OK)   
      {
          return buffer;
      }
      else
      {
          return "нет доступа к серверу";
      }
      //выводим полученные данные на стандартный вывод (консоль)         
      //else      
        //выводим сообщение об ошибке
        //text<< "Ошибка! " << errorBuffer << endl;     
}
else
     return "ошыбка curl";


             }
```

Comment: *"приложение при запросе вылетает"* - отлаживать пробовали? какая ошибка?

Comment: @VTT, и так же ясно, что невалидный url...

Comment: Что делает метод `ToStringUS`? Покажите его.

Comment: это преобразоване плохого системного стринга в адекватный обычный

Comment: добавил в ответ функцыю

Comment: Раз уж вы используете c++cli, то почему бы не использовать вместо curl родные дотнетные средства, как я вам уже предлагал: `HttpClient`, `WebClient`, `WebRequest`?

Comment: Зверский метод, этот ваш `ToStringUS`. Создается ненужная пустая строка; создается ненужный контекст; выполняется преобразование в `char*`, затем выполняется преобразование в `string`... Хотя достаточно **одного** преобразования сразу в нужный тип. Используйте подходящую [функцию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx), а именно: из `marshal_cppstd.h`.

Comment: Дайте пример пожалуйста, я когда то очень мучаюсь с этим системным типом строки и нашёл спасительный код как в функции выше если можно это сделать одной строчкой я только за по идеи так string a = marshal_context(this->richTextBox1->Text);
  но оно ошибку выдаёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url += Uri::EscapeDataString(this->richTextBox1->Text);
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4550600/4928642

---

PS: `gcnew String(URLget(url).c_str())` - так себе идея, вероятно...

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: URLget ето пользовательская функция внутри запрос на curl

Comment: Ошыбка 1>...Form1.h(284): warning C4832: лексема "." недопустима после UDT "System::Uri"
1>          c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.dll: см. объявление "System::Uri"
1>...\Form1.h(284): error C2275: System::Uri: недопустимое использование этого типа в качестве выражения
1>          c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.dll: см. объявление "System::Uri"
1>...\Form1.h(284): error C2228: выражение слева от ".EscapeDataString" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
1>

Comment: ё. `Uri->EscapeDataStringё` 2. не важно, чья она

Comment: В C++/CLI статический метод вызывается через два двоеточия: `Uri::EscapeDataString`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо :)

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка, ответ обновлён.

Comment: Спасибо вам всем. заработало. Простите за банальные ошибки работаю в visual studio 2010 где нет каких либо подсказок или авто дополнений. А 2008 визуалка на обновлённую десятку не стает